# 502 gateway error with meteor, browser policy, HTTP connecting to S3

Tags: meteor, nginx, docker, amazon-s3, dockerfile

I am using meteor with the `BrowerPolicy` package and `Meteor Up` with the `abernix/meteord:base` [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/abernix/meteord/) to deploy my app to a EC2 instance. I use HTTPS using nginx all on the same server. The trouble comes when I allow connections to an AWS S3 bucket using the following line:

```
BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('*.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com');
```

It works locally but when I deploy to the EC2 server, I get a `502 bad gateway` error for the entire app.

I have [read](https://github.com/meteorhacks/mup-frontend-server/issues/7) that this problem can sometimes be due to the header size being too large and that it can be fixed by changing `proxy_buffer_size 8k;` in the `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/CHECKEDID/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` file. I checked and my header size is 499 for a random svg that I have S3.

If indeed I need to make a change to the docker image to have this larger header size, how do I do that? I believe that this is the [source repo for the docker image](https://github.com/abernix/meteord). If I am totally off base and there is a different problem, please let me know that too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. So it turns out to be a configuration error with nginx. I configured my EC2 instance using [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04). In order to fix nginx, I first logged into my cluster and opened this file:

```
sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

I then added the `proxy_buffer_size 8k;` line to the `server` block of the configuration file. Finally, I checked the syntax with `sudo nginx -t` and restarted nginx `nginx restart`. That was it!

The best part is that since I configured my nginx instance manually and deploy my meteor instance on top of this running on port 3000, these settings persist even after I deploy new versions of my app.